# Como retornar corretamente os valores de cálculos com decimais em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho seguinte código alguém poderia ajudar como seria solução para isso.

---

```
var resultado  =(parseFloat(126,79) +  parseFloat(237,00)).toFixed(2);
```

**resultado do javascript =** 363,00

**valor correto =** 363,79

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que é isso que quer:

```js
 

var resultado  = parseFloat("126,79".replace(',', '.')) + parseFloat("237,00".replace(',', '.'));
console.log(resultado);

//valor correto = 363,79
```

A razão para isso acontecer é que `parseFloat()` quando encontra a virgula exclui o que vem a seguir e visto que esses valores começam por ser strings pode simplesmente fazer um [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) da virgula por ponto

Caso o resultado vá ser um valor com 3 casas decimais pode arredondar da seguinte forma:

```js
var resultado  = parseFloat("126,79".replace(',', '.')) +  parseFloat("237,201".replace(',', '.'));
console.log('Sem arredondar: ' +resultado);
resultado = Math.round(resultado * 100) / 100; // arredondar para 2 casas decimais
console.log('Arredondado: ' +resultado);

//valor correto = 363.991
```

Comment: perfeito obrigado resolvido.

Comment: De nada @EduardoSampaio, ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score 2):

Utilize "." ao inves de ","

```
 var resultado  =(parseFloat(126.79) +  parseFloat(237.00))
```

Answer (score 1):

O separador de decimal é `.` e não `,`. Da maneira como você fez, os números estão sendo considerados inteiros e não decimais.

```js
var valor1 = parseFloat(126.79);
var valor2 = parseFloat(237.00);
var resultado  = valor1 + valor2;
console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 1):

O uso da vírgula está errado, quando se usa número, não se usa vírgula, a vírgula é representada pelo ponto em JavaScript. o uso do `parseFloat()`, está fazendo parse do que ele considera número, ou seja, o valor que vem após a vírgula é descartado:

```
var v1 = '126,79'; //recebe valor 1 em string
var v2 = '237,00'; //recebe valor 2 em string
v1 = v1.replace(/\,/gi,'.'); //troca a vírgula por ponto do valor 1
v2 = v2.replace(/\,/gi,'.'); //troca a vírgula por ponto do valor 2
var resultado = (parseFloat(v1) + parseFloat(v2)).toFixed(2); 

console.log(resultado);
```